# Does there exist a torsion-free compact Hausdorff topological group?

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, torsion-groups

Let $G$ be a compact Hausdorff topological group. Does $G$ have torsion elements? I couldn't find examples of torsion-free compact Hausdorff topological groups. If $G$ is a Lie Group it should be true. Hausdorff cannot be omitted, because every group with the trivial topology is compact.

Comment: [For a Lie group it is true](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257342). For the $p$-adic integers it is false.

Comment: @AnneBauval thank you. Good example. Then in a compact Lie group the torsion elements are even dense! Do you know maybe a characterization or cirteria when it is true?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302657)